# Changes not showing in front end when modifying .twig file? opencart 3.0.3.6

Tags: opencart-3

When I am changing in the modification file twig file changes not reflect in admin panel. I'm using opencart 3.0.3.6 and installed extension PDF invoice pro but The download pdf icon is not displayed in the user account section (order list or order detail).
 I am checking in admin controller file weather data is coming or not from the database with the help of  var_dump but data perfectly coming from database but Buttons are not showing even after this. I think there is some problem in twig file. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OC version 3.0.3.6 has a bug. you can try to download this extension to resolve issue. https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=40603&filter_category_id=8&filter_license=0

Comment: When is this  bug going to be fixed. Pathetic